# Asking about add date in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I have code like this

```php
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function getdate() {
    var tt = document.getElementById('txtDate').value;
    var ct = document.getElementById('package').value;

    var date = new Date(tt);
    var newdate = new Date(date);
    newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + ct);

    var mm = newdate.getMonth()+1;
    var dd = newdate.getDate();
    var yyy = newdate.getFullYear();

    var someFormattedDate = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyy;
   document.getElementById('EndDate').value = someFormattedDate;
}
</script>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Start Tour</label>
    <input type="date" id="txtDate" name="start_date" required> 
</div>

<p></p>

<label> Ending Tour</label>
<input type="text" id="EndDate" name="end_date" required>   


<label>Nama Package</label>
<select class="form-control" id="package" name="package" onChange="getdate()">
    <option value= disabled>--Pilih Package Tour--</option>
    <?php
    $sql = mysql_query("select * from package");
    while ($lihat = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $lihat['lama_hari']; ?>"><?php echo $lihat['nama_package'] ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

When I run this code, I get the following result:

[image]

Why do I get this date in *Ending Tour*?

I count add date with the value from database of nama package, the value is `1` in database.
The result should be `09/03/2016`, not `09/21/2016`

I have no idea why the result becomes like that. I'm beginner here.

Comment: So you want to add `x` number of days to the date selected by the user where `x` is the value of `<select id="package">`?

Comment: What you actual want ?

Comment: because you set `document.getElementById('EndDate').value = someFormattedDate;` in your code thats why the `Ending Tour` has a value

Comment: yes i want to add value from id package

Comment: what i want is when i select dropdown in the nama package, the date is counting from value of package. and the result will show in tgl ending tour with format date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because your variable named ct is string type, First convert it to int type.

```
newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + parseInt(ct));
```

Comment: thank you for helping  :) It's Work. That's what i want.

Answer (score 2):

use momentJS http://jsfiddle.net/VtoCorleone/jbgUt/2/ this is good for convert, adding, subracting etc dates in javascript

don't forget to include it to your html

```
moment(date, "YYYY-MM-DD").add('days', 10); // 10 = the days add
```